# Finding a coefficient of $x^6$ in the expansion $(x-1)^5 (x+1)^5$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Find the coefficient of $x^6$ in the expansion $(x-1)^5 (x+1)^5$.

Is this question binomial? I understand the basiscs of the question but am unsure of how to complete the second part of the question.

Any assistance is greatly appreciated.

Thank you.

Comment: note $(x-1)(x+1)=x^2-1$ you should be able to go from here

Answer (score 7):

See that $(x - 1)^5(x + 1)^2 = \big((x - 1)(x + 1)\big)^5 = (x^2 - 1)^5$. This is a binomial in which the "variable" is $x^2$. The coefficient of $x^6$ is the same as the coefficient of $t^3$ in $(t - 1)^5$.

Answer (score 0):

It is a binomial equation using formula (a+b)^n 
The simple method is to simply one by one and then multiply both to get x^6

(x-1)^5= x^5 - 5c1(x^4)(1) +5c2(x^3) -5c3x^2 +5c4x^1..... 
(x+1)^5= x^5 + 5c1(x^4)(1) +5c2(x^3) +5c3x^2 +5c4x^1....

Multiply both to get x^6: (x^5 - 5x^4 + 10x^3 - 10x^2 + 5x) X (x^5 + 5x^4 + 10x^3 + 10x^2 + 5x) 
You get: 5x^6 - 50x^6 + 100x^6 -50x^6 +5x^6

Total coeff of x^6: 10